# Fetching data from an API in Node and storing it to export to CSV

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I have a list of countries (array) that I'd like to loop over and search with the country name in the API here: https://restcountries.eu. I'd like to store some of the returned country data in a variable which I will then export to a csv.

I am using 2 Node files one to clean the countries and one to convert to csv.

First I use the fetch API to grab the data

```
let list = [];

Promise.all(currentCountries.map((country)=>{
    fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${country}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
}))
.then((data)=>{
    list.push(data)
})
```

and then I use another file with the json-2-csv library to convert the `list` variable stored above to a csv

```
const fs = require('fs')
const converter = require('json-2-csv')
const list = require('./countryCleaning')


let json2csvCallback = function (err, csv) {
    if (err) throw err;
    fs.writeFile('cleanedCountryCodes.csv', csv, 'utf8', function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log("FS Error")
        } else {
            console.log("everything has worked")
        }
    })
};

converter.json2csv(list, json2csvCallback)
```

I keep getting nulls in the csv and I have no idea why. Can't tell if the problem is in the promises or the conversion to csv. Any problems you see? Is there a way for me to see the `list` in the first file? console.log doesn't work because it always runs before the async code finishes and gives me null of course.

My understanding of promises/async is still very basic so I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: since you're not returning anything in the `.map` callback, then of course the data is an array of undefined  - also, how is `list` exported from `require('./countryCleaning')` - seems like it could possibly be empty - not sure where you're getting nulls from though

Answer (score 0):

Need to return something from `then`

and export this **promise** from file same as **list**

then use this promise instead of list

Comment: he is returning `response.json()` in `.then` ... it's the `.map` callback that isn't returing anything

Comment: Yes, its true. He is returning first time ```response.json()``` 
but parent nothing returning. so need to return list

Comment: Oh, yeah, see what you mean about which .then you're talking about ... still, the .map needs to be fixed first